# Is there a way of splitting a word into 3 different parts in python?

Tags: python, string, split

```
char = "RV49CJ0AUTS172Y"
```

**To get this output:**

```
separated = "RV49C-J0AUT-S172Y"
```

I have tried:

```
split_strings = []
             n = 5
             for index in range(0, len(name), n):
                split_strings.append(name[index : index + n])
```

But that did not go as I wanted
[This shows a good method but I want them on the same line with dashes between them](https://www.javatpoint.com/program-to-divide-a-string-in-n-equal-parts)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could expand on the logic behind spliting? What happens if the length of the string is not divisible by 3?

Comment: You could simply use: `s[0:5] + "-" + s[5:10] + "-" + s[10:]` (after renaming `char` to `s`, because `char` is not a good name for a string) as long as the string is 10-15 characters in length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in **one-line**, using  `re`

```
import re
string = "RV49CJ0AUTS172Y"

separated = "-".join(re.findall('.{%d}' % (len(string) / 3), string))

print(separated)
```

[**Output**]

```
RV49C-J0AUT-S172Y
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is: the question asks for "3 different parts" and the answer has no magic number 3 at all. Why would this give 3 parts? Actually it's just by accident, because `string` happens to have 15 characters. And that's why we get [follow-up questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70486630/is-there-a-way-of-splitting-a-word-into-3-equal-parts-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Your code almost works, just calculate the amount of characters needed (`n`) instead of hard-coding it to 5. And for the final result, use `"-".join(...)` to mix all the elements of the array together into a single string.

```
char = "RV49CJ0AUTS172Y"
split_strings = []
n = len(char) // 3
for index in range(0, len(char), n):
    split_strings.append(char[index: index + n])
print("-".join(split_strings))
```