# Is there a way of splitting a word into equal parts in python?

Tags: python, string, input, split, user-input

I asked this question a few weeks ago and I got an answer [this is the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129585/is-there-a-way-of-splitting-a-word-into-3-different-parts-in-python)

But I need the output to be separated into equal parts whatever the length of the string is so in the first post I made I had this answer and it worked great as I needed thanks to (AziMez) he gave me the code and worked great

**Code**:

```
import re
string = "RV49CJ0AUTS172Y"

separated = "-".join(re.findall('.{%d}' % 5, string))

print(separated)
```

**and I had this output which is what I wanted at the time**:

```
RV49C-J0AUT-S172Y
```

**But now I made the thing user based so the user inputs a length to the string and it separates the string into equal parts like if I had this input**:

```
RV49CJ0AUTS172Y
```

**I get this output**:

```
RV49C-J0AUT-S172Y
```

**and this is what I had gotten originally but I don't work on all lengths
For example**
**This is a 12 character string**:

```
char = B1NS8XMA0LO5
```

**I want to get this output**:

```
separated = B1NS-8XMA-0LO5
```

**I can always change the number to 4 in the original code like this**:

```
separated = "-".join(re.findall('.{%d}' % 4, string))
```

But I can't keep it this way because the user input  will vary from time to time and I want this to be done based on the user input I want the char to be separated into equal parts which are separated by a hyphen(Like how I did in the output part)
Thanks

Comment: 15/3=5, 12/3=4, notice something?

Comment: What would be the output of the program if user inputs 11 char length string? How do you handle case that are not multiple by 3?

Comment: No, I will put an exception for this problem only length that can be separated into 3 equal parts will work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way of splitting a word into 3 different parts in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129585/is-there-a-way-of-splitting-a-word-into-3-different-parts-in-python)

Comment: Why did you accept the solution over there if it did not solve your problem? It did not do what you asked for. It did not split a string into 3 pieces. It split a string every 5th character. That's not the same. I fixed it now.

Comment: Well, it did because when I posted the post back then I had a fixed length of 15 so it was the thing I was looking for but now I made the thing user-based so I needed another answer to the same question but kind of a different way, and thanks for the other answer it worked as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
length = int(len(string) / 3)
separated = "-".join(re.findall('.{%d}' % length, string))
```