# Separating strings based on user-input python

Tags: python, string, input, split, user-input

I [posted this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70486630/is-there-a-way-of-splitting-a-word-into-equal-parts-in-python) earlier today and I got my answer but I wanna try something else in case of any changes that I possibly I make to my script so if this got a solution I would be grateful.

You can view the original code by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70486630/is-there-a-way-of-splitting-a-word-into-equal-parts-in-python) to my other question but here is a quick look at it, it won't cover the whole thing but here it is:

```
import re
string = "RV49CJ0AUTS172Y"

length = int(len(string) / 3)
separated = "-".join(re.findall('.{%d}' % length, string))

print(separated)
```

**So I have this:**

```
2 = 14
3 = 12-15-18-21
4 = 12-16
5 = 10-5
```

This is what I need for the separation part, the numbers on the left are the number of parts that I want the string to be separated too, and the numbers on the right are the lengths that the user may input and based on the input of the user the string should be separated according to where the number goes back to.
For example, if the user chose 18 as length then the string should be separated into 3 parts if the user chooses 16 then the string will be separated into 4 parts, and so on.

```
Char_18 = AS0MN5R1V85HN10OLA
separated = AS0MN5-R1V85H-N10OLA

Char_16 = NAH9186GMZLO1P09
separated = NAH9-186G-MZLO-1P09
```

So how do I apply this to my script?
Any help would be great!

Comment: Please clarify what you want.  You mention "the separation part", without defining this paret? Also, don't reference a previous question for code, you need to provide a stand alone question with a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Ok so if the user inputs a length of 18 the string gets separated into 3 parts and so on with the other numbers so basically whatever length the user inputs it will be separated into the number of parts that length is stored in like I showed up there if the user chooses the length 16 the string get separated into 4 different parts if 18 length is chosen the string gets separated into 3 different parts

Comment: Why does the string get separated into three parts?  What happens if the user inputs a length of 14?

Comment: Oh and for the code don't worry I added only the essential part there is some stuff that doesn't matter are in the previous post so nothing to worry about because this is a follow-up question but it's not related to the previous one but you can say have the same concept but in another structure of code.

Comment: than it gets separated into 2 parts

Comment: You see the numbers I provided are like a library but I don't know how to apply them to my code

Comment: Si I Have this doesn't explain the logic behind the list of numbers>  For example, since 13 can fall into a 3 or 4 partition result, which is selected and why?

Comment: that list is not supposed to be code it is supposed to better explain what I am trying to say it's like the number on the left is how many parts is the string supposed to get separated to and the numbers on the right are the numbers declaring in how many parts the string will get separated to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer if anyone wants it in the future so here it is:

```
import re
chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
numbers = "0123456789"
all = chars + numbers
while True:
    length = int(input("Select the length you want for your key: "))
    if 5 <= length <= 21:
        break
length_1 = 0
div_2 = 14
div_3 = 12,15,18,21
div_4 = 16,20
div_5 = 10,5
if length % div_2 == 0:
    length_1 = 2
elif any(length % i == 0 for i in div_3):        
    length_1 = 3
elif any(length % i == 0 for i in div_4):
    length_1 = 4
elif any(length % i == 0 for i in div_5):
    length_1 = 5
key = "".join(random.sample(all, length))
length_2 = int(len(key) / length_1)
separated = "-".join(re.findall('.{%d}' % length_2, key)
```

This is part of my code I couldn't post a direct answer because if anyone tries to use it they will be so confused but the main part that can answer your question is this:

```
while True:
    length = int(input("Select the length you want for your key: "))
    if 5 <= length <= 21:
        break
length_1 = 0
div_2 = 14
div_3 = 12,15,18,21
div_4 = 16,20
div_5 = 10,5
if length % div_2 == 0:
    length_1 = 2
elif any(length % i == 0 for i in div_3):        
    length_1 = 3
elif any(length % i == 0 for i in div_4):
    length_1 = 4
elif any(length % i == 0 for i in div_5):
    length_1 = 5
```

and this:

```
length_2 = int(len(key) / length_1)
separated = "-".join(re.findall('.{%d}' % length_2, key)
```

I hope this will be helpful for anyone who has the same question.